Python Code failing : dedupe library error
I am trying to learn about dedupe library . I am trying to match name which are more than 80% match.
Sharing code and error . Please help
import dedupe
from Levenshtein import distance

def test():


    # Sample data (replace with your actual library data)
    data = [
        {'name': 'Alice Smith', 'address': '123 Main St', 'phone': '555-1212'},
        {'name': 'Alice SmIth', 'address': '123 Main Street', 'phone': '555-1213'},
        {'name': 'Bob Johnson', 'address': '456 Elm St', 'phone': '555-3434'},
        {'name': 'Charlie Brown', 'address': '789 Maple Ave', 'phone': '555-5656'},
    ]

    # Define fields for comparison (adjust based on your data)
    # Define data fields and comparison functions
    fields = [
        {'field': 'name', 'comparators': ['name_similarity']},

    ]

    # Define similarity functions - customize based on your matching criteria
    def name_similarity(s1, s2):
        # Implement your name comparison logic here (e.g., Levenshtein distance, etc.)
        distance1 = distance(s1, s2)
        similarity = 1 - (distance1 / max(len(s1), len(s2)))  # Normalize distance to 0-1 similarity
        return similarity



    # Set thresholds for field-wise and overall similarity (adjust as needed)
    deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields)
    deduper.threshold( threshold=0.8)

    # Process the data for deduplication
    deduped_data = deduper.dedupe(data)

    # Print the deduplicated results
    print("Deduplicated Data:")
    for cluster in deduped_data:
        print(cluster)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

.....
C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Scripts\python.exe C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\matching.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\datamodel.py", line 152, in typify_variables
    variable_type = definition["type"]
                    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\matching.py", line 45, in <module>
    test()   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\matching.py", line 32, in test
    deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\api.py", line 1155, in __init__
    self.data_model = datamodel.DataModel(variable_definition)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\datamodel.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.primary_variables, all_variables = typify_variables(variable_definitions)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\datamodel.py", line 161, in typify_variables
    raise KeyError( KeyError: "Missing variable type: variable specifications are dictionaries that must include a type definition, ex. {'field' : 'Phone', type: 'String'}"

Process finished with exit code 1


sry, which version of dedupe are you using?

My answer is for dedupe>=2.0 and the code may not work on other library versions.
Also I would suggest to check this manuals, they have a lot of usefull information:
https://dedupeio.github.io/dedupe-examples/docs/csv_example.html

Back to your error - when intializing dedupe.Dedupe class it is expecting from you to pass information about field types (see fields variable in the code below).

Also your data should be formatted a bit different, each row should have an id. Check variable data_d in the code below.

One more thing that you are missing - list of labeled examples. Basically several matching pairs and several distinct pairs (better to have at least 10 pairs in each group). They are stores in labeled_example variable in the code.

Lastly if you plan to use custom comparators - you should change field_type to Custom. Otherwise dedupe will use standard comparator based on field type (String/Category/Float etc.).


check this link for all available variable definitions:
https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/Variable-definition.html
import dedupe
from Levenshtein import distance

# Define similarity functions - customize based on your matching criteria
def name_similarity(s1, s2):
    # Implement your name comparison logic here (e.g., Levenshtein distance, etc.)
    distance1 = distance(s1, s2)
    similarity = 1 - (distance1 / max(len(s1), len(s2)))  # Normalize distance to 0-1 similarity
    return similarity

def test():
    
    # Sample data (replace with your actual library data)
    data = [
        {'name': 'Alice Smith', 'address': '123 Main St', 'phone': '555-1212'},
        {'name': 'Alice SmIth', 'address': '123 Main Street', 'phone': '555-1213'},
        
        {'name': 'Bob Johnson', 'address': '456 Elm St', 'phone': '555-3434'},
        {'name': 'Bob Johnson', 'address': '457 Elm St', 'phone': '555-3434'},
        
        {'name': 'Charlie Brown', 'address': '789 Maple Ave', 'phone': '555-5656'},
        {'name': 'Charlie Brown', 'address': '789 Meple Ave', 'phone': '555-5656'},
    
        {'name': 'Karry Perry', 'address': '102 Meple Ave', 'phone': '555-3556'},
        {'name': 'Karri Perry', 'address': '102 Meple Ave', 'phone': '555-3556'},
    
    ]

    # give examples of matched Rows and distinct Rows
    labeled_examples = {
        "match": [(data[0], data[1]),
                  (data[2], data[3]),
                  (data[4], data[5])],
        "distinct": [(data[0], data[2]),
                  (data[2], data[4]),
                  (data[4], data[6])],
    }
    
    data_d = {i:record for i, record in enumerate(data)}
    
    
    # Define fields for comparison (adjust based on your data)
    # Define data fields and comparison functions
    fields = [
        {'field': 'name', 'type': 'Custom', 'comparator': name_similarity},
        # {'field': 'address', 'type': 'String'},
        {'field': 'phone', 'type': 'String'},
    
    ]
        
    deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields)
    deduper.prepare_training(data_d)    
    deduper.mark_pairs(labeled_examples)


    # # # !! This line required to run this example - very small dataset
    # # # !! Remove it if your dataset have more than 10 examples in each class
    # # # this is GridSearchCV.cv parameter for creating KFold
    deduper.classifier.cv = 2

    # # # train
    _ = deduper.train()

    clustered_dupes = deduper.partition(data_d, threshold=0.5)
    
    print('# duplicate sets', len(clustered_dupes))
    
    cluster_membership = {}
    for cluster_id, (records, scores) in enumerate(clustered_dupes):
        for record_id, score in zip(records, scores):
            cluster_membership[record_id] = {
                "Cluster ID": cluster_id,
                "confidence_score": score
            }
    
    print(cluster_membership)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

output:
{0: {'Cluster ID': 0, 'confidence_score': 0.82329434}, 
 1: {'Cluster ID': 0, 'confidence_score': 0.82329434}, 
 2: {'Cluster ID': 1, 'confidence_score': 0.96056044}, 
 3: {'Cluster ID': 1, 'confidence_score': 0.96056044}, 
 4: {'Cluster ID': 2, 'confidence_score': 0.96056044}, 
 5: {'Cluster ID': 2, 'confidence_score': 0.96056044}, 
 6: {'Cluster ID': 3, 'confidence_score': 0.9537174}, 
 7: {'Cluster ID': 3, 'confidence_score': 0.9537174}}


Hello @Johnny Cheesecutter thanks for solution.but will this solution work with actual data where I have 500k records  . and in that case do I  need pass more data to train the model ?

Honestly, didn't use this library myself. The more training data you have - the better. So if possible provide in training everything that you have. But they ask for at least 10 record of matches and distincts.
My view that the library is not optimised from performance/speed of processing view. Luckily you need to do run everything once. And final clustering results are very promising.

Hello @johnny Cheesecutter. I have shared one issue which I am getting while running prepare training . Do you have any idea about it . It would be great . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78325057/dedupe-library-issue-with-csv-file
