Dedupe Library issue with csv file
I am trying to learn dedupe library by running one very small example . I am getting some error . PLease help
import dedupe
from Levenshtein import distance
# Define similarity functions - customize based on your matching criteria
def name_similarity(s1, s2):
    # Implement your name comparison logic here (e.g., Levenshtein distance, etc.)
    distance1 = distance(s1, s2)
    similarity = 1 - (distance1 / max(len(s1), len(s2)))  # Normalize distance to 0-1 similarity
    return similarity


if __name__ == '__main__':
# Sample data (list of dictionaries)
    data = {18709931: {'id': '18709931', 'name': 'TEST', 'ent_num': '8256364', 'ent_nm_txt': 'TST Corporation'},
            18484906: {'id': '18484906', 'name': 'VESTCOM', 'ent_num': '8256364', 'ent_nm_txt': 'TST Corporation'},
            18709961: {'id': '18709961', 'name': 'TESTMATERIALS', 'ent_num': '8256364', 'ent_nm_txt': 'TST Corporation'},
            19415694: {'id': '19415694', 'name': 'TEST', 'ent_num': '8256364', 'ent_nm_txt': 'TST Corporation'}}




    # Define a schema
    fields = [
        {'field': 'name', 'type': 'Custom', 'comparator': name_similarity},
        {'field': 'ent_num', 'type': 'Exact'},

    ]

    # Initialize a deduper
    deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields)

    # Active learning loop to label examples
    deduper.prepare_training(data)

    # Active learning loop
    dedupe.console_label(deduper)

    # Train the deduper
    deduper.train()

    # Save the trained model to disk
    with open('dedupe_model.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        dedupe.pickle.dump(deduper, f)

error I am getting while running training

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Python_Projects\Python_extra_code\test_dedupe_code.py", line 30,
in 
deduper.prepare_training(data)   File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\api.py", line 1424, in
prepare_training
self.active_learner = labeler.DedupeDisagreementLearner(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py", line 430, in
init
self.mark(examples, labels)   File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py", line 391, in
mark
learner.fit(self.pairs, self.y)   File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py", line 117, in
fit
self.current_predicates = self.block_learner.learn(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\dedupe\training.py", line 58, in
learn
coverable_dupes = frozenset.union(*match_cover.values())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: unbound method frozenset.union() needs an argument
Process finished with exit code 1


Hello ) The problem is with the input data. I guess the dedupe don't handle well "corner" cases (or "special" cases). First of all dedupe rely on non-custom fields to create 'blocks'. This 'blocks' are groups of very similar items, basically to search duplicates only in the same block... Ok, so back to your question, dedupe will closely look on 'ent_num' field (only non-custom), however in your example you have same value  8256364 in all records. And this is what crashed dedupee. If you'll change at least several ent_num values to 8256232 your issue will be solved. Hope this helps.

Simply speaking if you have all values equal to the same number, dedupe can't break data into blocks (basically your data is one block) and this crashes dedupe.

but i need to find  dupes within one ent_num. its like ent_num is grouping data under one and then find dupes in that group. are u saying i should pass data where i need to have at least 2 different ent_num ?

Dedupee will optimize it's algortihm to search in Exactly one ent_num. You can pass all your data (all ent_nums) at once.

or add at least several "dummy" rows with other ent_num

OK let me try that  and confirm

I'm referring to the docs part about "Smart comparison" and specifically "predicates for defining blocks". Basically if you want to speed up search you need to find a field in your data that can be used for this 'blocking' mechanism.
https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/how-it-works/Making-smart-comparisons.html#predicate-blocks

Or better idea - You can use field name both as a Custom field and as a blocking field:
[
{'field': 'name', 'type': 'Custom', 'comparator': name_similarity},
{'field': 'name', 'type': 'Text'}
]

The problem is that dedupee tries to use ent_num for creating blocks, but you have the single value in this field (i.e. always equal to some value like 8256364).
If you want to find duplicates only in name inside single value of ent_num=8256364 the best advise would be to use name both for Custom distance and for blocking (and basically exclude ent_num):
[ 
{'field': 'name', 'type': 'Custom', 'comparator': name_similarity}, 
{'field': 'name', 'type': 'String'}  # will allow to use for block search
] 

UPD: updated based on comment from pbh

hello @johnny cheesecutter.data file has 850 records .while creating label i did 10/10 positive, 13/10 negative. raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

even after passing  deduper.prepare_training(data_d,sample_size=150) getting same error

Hi, Could you pls provide teceback of the ValueError. I tried running the code above on 850 records in dataset with console_labeling and it worked for me. I did label 10/10 positive and 10/10 negative (more or less same as you). However I didn't pass sample parameter anywhere in the code.
As for prepare_training(sample_size=..) - it doesn't influence the training. During training you are using labeled examples. Thus your train(...sample_size..) can't be more than 23 ( = 10 positive + 13 negative).

Pls update the Question and add details on the new error and code that you are using (if possible).

Hi @johnny Cheesecutter. Its resolved moment I added {'field': 'name', 'type': 'String'}. I am not sure if it si mandatory

Great ) Nice to know that you solved the issue.
